# laravel how to debug a RESTful controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, phpstorm

I have this controller

```
class APIV1CustomerController extends BaseController{
    public function getIndex(){
        return "super new look";
    }

    public function postRegister(){
        return "you have entered "+Input::get('fullName')+" as fullName parameter and "+Input::get('mobileNumber')+" as mobileNumber parameter";
    }
}
```

I am trying to call the `register` function from IOS, I have some problems with the returing data. Thus, I need to debug that function.

when I return just simple test like `return "test"`, it works well from IOS. but when I return the code I showed to you, some problem accrues, I can solve the problem myself from the IOS side but I need to debug the `postRegister` to check some issues.

when I was using `J2EE` web service, I can simple print some data to the console in my `eClipse`  that is why I am asking if there is any way to do that in laravel.

Thanks

#### I am using php storm IDE

Comment: what is the problem that occurs? how do you know it is not working?

Comment: You can use Chrome extension `Postman` or Firefox addon `RESTClient` to debug your RESTful controllers.

Comment: Instead of creating `APIV1CustomerController` create `CustomerController` with namespace Api\V1. You can test api inside firefox developer tools.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange now I have fixed the problem but after some efforts. The problem was that I forgot to but `&` between parameters. that problem would be easily if I had some debugging tool that could show me the request received by laravel. I didn't expect that the problem is that so I check almost all the code, 4 hours working :(

Comment: @SUB0DH I didn't know about them. I like Chrome, I will install it immediately. Hope it works fine with me.

Answer (score 3):

This might be useful: https://github.com/mlanin/laravel-api-debugger

It's a laravel package specifically built for assisting with APIs.

Answer (score 0):

this might be irrelevant, but i learned a lot from this article when debugging api and jquery back then. http://www.openlogic.com/wazi/bid/188084/jQuery-and-Ajax-Error-Detection-and-Handling.

the first step is to see if there's any functions in your IOS which will notify you when you have an error after the http call, so that you know you actually are getting an error, ex. 404, 500 etc. Because if you are getting 200, most likely you don't need more advanced debug tool other than print.

server log is another friend which is very helpful in these white screen case, it'll tell you the exact error when 500 error happens. Ex. last error I got on my server was telling me a class name is not found, although it runs fine in my local.